# Parsing simple JSON data for windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I've becomes stumped when trying to parse some json data, and it's mainly because it's simpler then I've dealt with before. so here is what the JSON looks like:

```
[ { "guid" : "782ba9b2-be03-4e1c-884c-a862a9d80bc7",
    "id" : 1016,
    "message" : "test",
    "tag" : "test",
    "username" : "asd"
  },
  { "guid" : "08aa59ca-af56-4a60-9304-e96a86d4832d",
    "id" : 1012,
    "message" : "test",
    "tag" : "test",
    "username" : "123"
  },
  { "guid" : "08aa59ca-af56-4a60-9304-e96a86d4832d",
    "id" : 1011,
    "message" : "test",
    "tag" : "test",
    "username" : "12"
  },
  { "guid" : "08aa59ca-af56-4a60-9304-e96a86d4832d",
    "id" : 1010,
    "message" : "test",
    "tag" : "test",
    "username" : "1"
  }
]
```

and this is my current code:

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string json = e.Result;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                {
                    GroupMessages results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GroupMessages>(json);
                    JObject jo = new JObject();
                    jo = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
                    List<GroupMessages> contentList = new List<GroupMessages>();
                    JArray items = (JArray)jo[""];
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < items.Count)
                    {
                        GroupMessages content = new GroupMessages();
                        tcUsername = items[count]["username"].ToString();
                        tcMessage = items[count]["message"].ToString();
                        tcGuid = items[count]["guid"].ToString();
                        tcTag = items[count]["tag"].ToString();

                        content.username = tcUsername;
                        content.message = tcMessage;
                        content.guid = tcGuid;
                        content.tag = tcTag;

                        contentList.Add(content);
                        count++;
                    }
                    generalList.ItemsSource = contentList.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Data.ToString());
            }

        }
```

and i *think* I know where the error is:

```
JArray items = (JArray)jo[""];
```

As most of the json I've ever worked with has been { "results": [ info here ]}, i'm unsure what to put here. leaving it blank causes it to not work, so i'm not sure how i work around this.

any help would be great.

Comment: @rene sadly not, "Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JToken` for partial result.

```
JToken jt = JToken.Parse(e.Result);
JArray items = (JArray)jt;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man, turns out there was another problem in my code, which stopped this working at first, but sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You get an JSON array so use the [JArray.Parse](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ParseJsonObject.htm)

```
//  jo = JObject.Parse(e.Result);
List<GroupMessages> contentList = new List<GroupMessages>();
JArray items = JArray.Parse(e.Result);
```